# Enabling CORS in Java Web Service

Tags: java, reactjs, web-services, cors

**NOTE: I already figured out the solution.  I'm just posting the issue and resolution in case others have a similar issue**

**Long story short:**

I'm getting this CORS error message on my browser's Developer Tools window when I have a REACT client side app make an HTTP post to a Java Web Server I have running on Payara server running from NetBeans:

> SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:3000' did not find
>   'http://localhost:3000' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response
>   header for cross-origin  resource at
>   'http://localhost:8080/DatabaseWebService/databaseConnectorMethod'.

For more info about CORS please refer to this site https://enable-cors.org/

**Long story detailed:**

I have a REACT project running on http://localhost:3000 making an HTTP post to a Java Web Service I have (DatabaseWebService) that is running on a local Payara Server version 4.1.1.  The Web Service URL that the REACT app is requesting is 'http://localhost:8080/DatabaseWebService/databaseConnectorMethod'

Everytime I run the REACT code I get the CORS error listed above.

Here's my REACT code making the http post request:

```
            const postData = new URLSearchParams();
            postData.append('var1', 'somedata1');
            postData.append('var2', 'somedata2');
            let axiosConfig = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'                
}
            };

        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/DatabaseWebService/databaseConnectorMethod', postData, axiosConfig)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("AXIOS POST RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("AXIOS POST ERROR: ", err);
            })
```

Here's my servlet code:

```
public class DatabaseConnectorServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        final protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            try {
                System.out.println("DatabaseConnectorServlet Received a HTTP POST");  

                String var1= request.getParameter("var1");
                String var2= request.getParameter("var2");
                System.out.println(var1 + var2);
                response.getWriter().print("I GOT YOUR MESSAGE");
            } catch (Exception ex) {                          
                response.getWriter().print(ex);
            }
        }
```

I put breakpoints in the Java code above and see it getting hit and I see that it executes all the commands including the response.getWriter().print with no issue.  However when I look at the browsers developer tools Console window I do see the CORS exception.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
In the Java Web Service app, you need to add some header(s) to allow CORS in the Response object.  Here's the updated Java code, note the extra response.addHeader line of code:

```
public class DatabaseConnectorServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    final protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            System.out.println("DatabaseConnectorServlet Received a HTTP POST");
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000"); //Here's the extra line needed to allow CORS to your server side code

            String var1 = request.getParameter("var1");
            String var2 = request.getParameter("var2");
            System.out.println(var1 + var2);
            response.getWriter().print("I GOT YOUR MESSAGE");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
            response.getWriter().print(ex);
        }
    }
```

With this updated code I can now see the sample "I GOT YOUR MESSAGE" text on the web browser Developer tool's console window where the React code is running.

This basically allows a http request from a different domain/port (i.e. in this case the REACT application) to access data from this java web service.

Also just so that you're aware, there are some other additional headers you can include (that I saw on other questions) that I didn't need for my situation, but maybe useful in yours.  Here are the additional headers and some sample values:

```
 response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin, X-Custom-Header, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Length, X-Kuma-Revision");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
```

Comment: in general case it's better to handle this in single place rather modifying headers per each request. Also it is not good idea to hard-code domains in the code since in production it will not `localhost:8080`

Comment: Understood.  I do agree with both of your points.   In other similar posts I saw people indicating to configure the server to accept CORS, but I don't recall actually seeing info how to do so.  I did also see plenty of answers on other related posts about adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response headers.  I'll look about how to configure it somehow in a single place, perhaps on the server itself, and look into updating the answer when I figure it out.